# Xcode 7/Swift 2.0, imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, swift2, xcode7

I am currently getting a head start in porting over an existing Swift app to have it work on iOS9. I'm unfortunately getting a runtime error when trying to run the app, which currently works in Xcode 6 and Swift 1.x. With this code:

```
let checkedImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImage(named: "checkbox-checked.png")!
    let tintImage = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    let view = UIImageView(image: tintImage)
    view.sizeToFit()
    return view
}()
```

I get the following error, which is happening on `UIImageView`'s constructor: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x177d80)`

I have no idea if this is a beta bug or otherwise.

EDIT: This is happening as of Xcode 7 beta 5.

EDIT 2: Looks like UIImageView is okay with the original image. Looks like it's been narrowed down to `imageWithRenderingMode`.

Comment: 1) check that image with name checkbox-checked.png exists
2) comment out all lines apart from "let view = UIImageView(image: tintImage)" and "return view". Does it give an error? If not, then comment back other lines one-by-one until you find the line which crashes your app. Then let us know which line does it

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk The error is occuring at the instantiation of `UIImageView` as I mentioned. Also as I said the code works fine in Xcode 6.

Comment: can you upload the source code? This error might be happening because of the place in which you call .checkedImage. Also, it is still a good idea to check that tintImage is not nil. Maybe some connections are not loaded in Xcode 7 and your UIImage is nil

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to pass in the full source code. `tintImage` is not `nil`, but the original image does seem to be okay. Updated/edited to note `imageWithRenderingMode`.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. There is nothing changed with `imageWithRenderingMode`. Go back to the first line and fix it. Rewrite your code so there are _no exclamation marks_.

Comment: How can I remove the UIImage exclamation point without getting a compile-time error?

Comment: I tried rewriting it so that the exclamation was removed and the next line being `image?.withRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)` and still the same error.

Comment: @J_P while you are unable to pass the full source code you can surely create a dummy app which will illustrate this issue without containing any other copyright protected code which you might have ;) and the benefit of doing this (in addition to the rest of the community being able to test it) is that you might be able to identify the problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up migrating the Xcode 6 codebase to Xcode 7 beta 5 as opposed to opening the already migrated Xcode 7 beta 4 codebase in Xcode 7 beta 5 and this error appears to be nonexistant now.